# Mutate case_when date time data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I am working with a nocturnal species and am trying to label GPS fixes recorded overnights by date and time periods. The GPS fixes were recorded between 19:00:00 one night and 05:00:00 the following morning for ~ 80 days. Each night period span two days (obviously). I want to organises the fixes by night as opposed to date so the animal movement isn't split in the middle of the active period. I am having issues getting this to work correctly. I would like to create a new column with an ID for a collection of days in a period (e.g. 1-week) but would also like to create a column for each separate night.

When I first read in the data it looks like the following (noting this is not my data but an example of 4 columns that exist within the dataset and its structure):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)

data <- read_csv("data/gps-fixes.csv")
```

| Fix_date_time | Animal_ID | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15/01/21 19:00 | 1 | -20.67891 | 132.87652 |
| 15/01/21 20:00 | 1 | -20.66652 | 132.88912 |
| 15/01/21 21:00 | 1 | -20.68752 | 132.92312 |
| 15/01/21 22:00 | 1 | -20.64652 | 132.88912 |
| 15/01/21 23:00 | 1 | -20.70652 | 132.88812 |
| 16/01/21 00:00 | 1 | -20.78652 | 132.88712 |
| 16/01/21 01:00 | 1 | -20.78652 | 132.88712 |
| 16/01/21 02:00 | 1 | -20.78652 | 132.88712 |
| 16/01/21 03:00 | 1 | -20.78652 | 132.88712 |
| 16/01/21 04:00 | 1 | -20.78652 | 132.88712 |
| 16/01/21 05:00 | 1 | -20.78652 | 132.88712 |

Fix_date_time is read in as a col_character() and the other three variables are col_double()
The date when first read in appears as DMY H:M

I then convert the date and time to date/time date using lubridate

```
data$Fix_date_time <- dmy_hm(data$Fix_date_time)
```

Which returns the following

| Fix_date_time | Animal_ID | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-15 19:00:00 | 1 | -20.67891 | 132.87652 |
| 2021-01-15 20:00:00 | 1 | -20.66652 | 132.88912 |
| 2021-01-15 21:00:00 | 1 | -20.68752 | 132.92312 |
| 2021-01-15 22:00:00 | 1 | -20.64652 | 132.88912 |
| 2021-01-15 23:00:00 | 1 | -20.70652 | 132.88812 |
| 2021-01-16 00:00:00 | 1 | -20.78652 | 132.88712 |
| 2021-01-16 01:00:00 | 1 | -20.78652 | 132.88712 |
| 2021-01-16 02:00:00 | 1 | -20.78652 | 132.88712 |
| 2021-01-16 03:00:00 | 1 | -20.78652 | 132.88712 |
| 2021-01-16 04:00:00 | 1 | -20.78652 | 132.88712 |
| 2021-01-16 05:00:00 | 1 | -20.78652 | 132.88712 |

The date time then displayed as a dttm vector.

If I then attempt to create a new column from a number of nights I get the incorrect output.
If I enter the following code:

```
data %<>% 
mutate(period = case_when(
       (Fix_date_time >= 2021-01-15 19:00:00) & (Fix_date_time <= 2021-01-21 05:00:00) ~ "Period-1",
       (Fix_date_time >= 2021-01-21 19:00:00) & (Fix_date_time <= 2021-01-28 05:00:00) ~ "Period-2",
       (Fix_date_time >= 2021-01-29 19:00:00) & (Fix_date_time <= 2021-02-02 05:00:00) ~ "Period-3"))
```

I instead end up with the last GPS fixes in each period ending the on the night before the end date at around 8pm (e.g. for "Period-1" the last fixes are around 22:00 on 2021-01-21). However if make it <= 19:00:00 for the end date in each period it works. While this is a work around for now, I want to figure out what I am doing wrong to fix it in the future.

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare the data with the same class. Try the following :

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)

data %<>% 
  mutate(period = case_when(
    Fix_date_time >= ymd_hms('2021-01-15 19:00:00') & 
    Fix_date_time <= ymd_hms('2021-01-21 05:00:00') ~ "Period-1",
    Fix_date_time >= ymd_hms('2021-01-21 19:00:00') & 
    Fix_date_time <= ymd_hms('2021-01-28 05:00:00') ~ "Period-2",
    Fix_date_time >= ymd_hms('2021-01-29 19:00:00') & 
    Fix_date_time <= ymd_hms('2021-02-02 05:00:00') ~ "Period-3"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly!

Comment: @Ronak Shah case_when() is described as using specific to more general conditions.  how would one include a count for all periods (1,2 &3)  Fix_date_time >= ymd_hms('2021-01-15 19:00:00')  & Fix_date_time <= ymd_hms('2021-02-02 05:00:00')~ "All Periods"

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the timetk library with its between_time function for cases like this. It is a tad bit more elegant than lubridate.

```
library(dplyr)
library(timetk)

data %>% 
  mutate(
    period = case_when(
      Fix_date_time %>% between_time('2021-01-15 19:00:00','2021-01-21 05:00:00') ~ 'Period-1',
      Fix_date_time %>% between_time('2021-01-21 19:00:00','2021-01-28 05:00:00') ~ 'Period-2',
      Fix_date_time %>% between_time('2021-01-29 19:00:00','2021-02-02 05:00:00') ~ 'Period-3',
  )
)
```